# Rails 3 with PostgreSQL: Problem with 'update_all' in joined table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, join

In Rails 3, I'm trying to use a statement like `self.children.joins(:parent).where(...).update_all(...)` to select a subset of records and update them all. This worked using MySQL but is not working with PostgreSQL. Is the Rails syntax wrong?

*Details*

Members belong to families, families have many members. The statement in question is in a Family instance method, so "self" is a family:

```
self.members.joins(:family).
    where('spouse_id > 0 OR child OR members.id = families.head_id').
    update_all("members.residence_location_id = #{self.residence_location_id}")
```

In other words, for a subset of members of this family, copy the family residence_location to the member residence_location.

This worked perfectly well in MySQL. When I changed to PostgreSQL, however, I get this error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
 LINE 1: UPDATE "members" INNER JOIN "families" ON "families"."id" = ...

UPDATE "members" INNER JOIN "families" ON "families"."id" = "members"."family_id" 
  SET members.residence_location_id = 27 
  WHERE ("members".family_id = 425) AND 
        (spouse_id > 0 OR child OR members.id = families.head_id)
```

Is my Rails statement incorrect but just happened to work in MySQL? Is there a way to fix it to work with PostgreSQL? Or perhaps a way to use MetaWhere?

Comment: The UPDATE SQL isn't [valid for PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html), MySQL has a bad habit of accepting non-standard SQL and thus corrupting the youth. You need to convince AR to produce `UPDATE members SET ... FROM families ...`. Or just do it all by hand with `connection.execute()`.

Comment: Thanks, mu. Just strange the Rails generates invalid queries.

Comment: Rails generates invalid SQL all the time, hence all the questions about why things break when deployed to Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this issue was probably caused by this, now resolved in Rails 3.1, issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/522